# Unable to move the #Weglot language switcher from bottom to top on my Shopify website

Tags: html, css

Recently I have installed the Weglot Language translation App into my Shopify eCommerce store. After installing it, under the settings page I have tried all the options to twick the CSS in order to bring the Weglot on the Storefront at the top right page. Unfortunately, nothing has worked for me. I have contacted the Weglot support and got the following resolutions. I tried all the resolutions but nothing has worked for me. Can someone please help to share the right CSS code so that once I put the 
 under my Theme.liquid file it starts working.

Website: https://www.bluecircle-coffee.com/

Resolutions provided by Weglot (NONE WORKED FOR ME)

1. The Weglot_here option:
   You can paste the code below into your Theme.liquid file (or into another liquid file), at the place you want the language switcher to be displayed.
2. The Switchers option:
   See in the documentation below, how to move the language switcher thanks to the Switchers.options to add to your Weglot.initialize code.

> Shopify - How to change the position of the language switcher (documentation with a video)
> Your Weglot.initialize code will be findable into your Shopify admin > Online Store > Themes > Action > Edit Code > weglot_switchers.liquid

Then, you will just have to replace the target element (".header-nav") with the CSS selector of the parent element where you want the language switcher to be placed.

For instance, if you want to add it to your menu

Your target line will be:
target: ".menu",

Reminder: To find the CSS selector:

- Right-click on the element you want to place the language switcher into.
- Go to "Inspect"
- Use the arrow on the top left of the console
- Right-Click on the targetted element
- Copy > Copy selector
- Paste the code in the "target" field.

3. The Weglot Anchors
   This option allows you to link Weglot to your own language switcher or to your native menu.
   As you can see in the documentation below, the Weglot Anchors are just links to add to your language switcher in order to manage the translation.

> https://developers.weglot.com/javascript/link-hooks#example-anchor

For instance, you create a "Languages" item menu with "English" and "Spanish" as sub-menus.
English will have the link "#Weglot-en" and Spanish will have the link "#Weglot-es".

Answer (score 1):

I'm Alexis from Weglot support, and I already talked to you in our email conversation.

I actually sent you a collaboration request on Shopify: did you receive it? You should have received an email at the same address as the owner of your Shopify store, and you should also have a notification in your Shopify admin.

Anyway, if you don't manage to accept it, you can go to your Shopify admin -> Online Store -> Themes -> Action -> Edit code, and edit your weglot_switchers.liquid file.

In it, you can put the following code:

```js
<script type="text/javascript"src="https://cdn.weglot.com/weglot.min.js"></script>
<script>
    Weglot.initialize({
        api_key: 'YOUR_KEY',
        switchers: [
        {
            // Same as button_style at root
            button_style: {
                full_name: true,
                with_name: true,
                is_dropdown: false,
                with_flags: true,
                flag_type: "circle",
                invert_flags: false
            },
            // Move switcher somewhere in the page
            location: {
                target: "#shopify-section-header > header > div > nav > div.nav-inner > div.nav-right",
                sibling: null
            }
        }
    ]
    });
</script>
```

And it should put the switcher just after your cart icon.

If it doesn't work well, please feel free to come back to us on support@weglot.com, and I will be glad to guide you to move your language switcher.

Best regards,

Comment: This is a Q&A website, not direct message. So, remember that 2 first paragraph are off-topic because they are talking about you and the OP.